# Silverlight sequential operation for Asynchronous operation

Tags: silverlight, asynchronous

I have 3 operation that need to process sequentially, they are

1. GetMainInformation
2. GetDetails1
3. GetDetails2

I'm doing this by code like below but I think it isn't clean. I want to know an alternative way to do async operation in sequential order.

```
GetMainInformation.Completed += GetDetails1;
GetDetails1.Completed += GetDetails2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Caliburn Micro's IResult and Coroutines. [How to ensure all properties have loaded in Silverlight ViewModel pattern (Concurrency Control?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105228/how-to-ensure-all-properties-have-loaded-in-silverlight-viewmodel-pattern-concur/6105970#6105970)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a queue. Something like this:

```
GetMainInformation.Completed += GetMainInformationCompleted
GetDetails1.Completed += GetDetails1Completed
GetDetails2.Completed += GetDetails2Completed
```

Start the request:

```
requestCounter = 3;
GetMainInformationAsync();
GetDetails1();
GetDetails2();
```

In each one of the completed functions:

```
void GetMainInformationCompleted()
{
  // Store result in member variable
  requestCounter--;
  if (requestCounter == 0)
  {
    ProcessRequest();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code must run in a specific order, and sequentially, why not have Getdetails2, called in the oncompletion of GetDetails1, etc so it works its way through? Or. Have your service have a function to call all 3, if the data is related, it maybe feasible to have a data structure with lists/arrays within it such as.

```
   String CustomerName, 
String Address, 
String PhoneNumber, 
List<orders> Orders, 
List<itemsMarked> ItemsMarked
```

Where the MainInfo goes to the customer parts, the details1 goes into orders and details2 into marked items etc.